# sendarp with multithreading function is not working for whole subnet (wifi environment)

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

I was trying to fetch Mac addrs of all the devices present in WiFi environment(whole subnet).

Initially when i ran the code approx it took 10 mins to get the result for whole subnet so in order to reduce the time i used multithreaded concept in windows machine but this method is not at all working.

I am pasting the code snippet below.
Even i tried different logic like running 255, 100, 50 ,2 threads at a time but still it failed.

I suspect synchronization issue in this but i don't have any idea to resolve this, so please help me in this getting done.

```
DWORD WINAPI GetMacAddrOfSubNet(LPVOID lpParam)
{

   DWORD dwRetVal;
   IPAddr DestIp = 0;
   IPAddr SrcIp = 0;       /* default for src ip */
   ULONG MacAddr[2];       /* for 6-byte hardware addresses */
   ULONG PhysAddrLen = 6;  /* default to length of six bytes */
   char look[100];

   strcpy(look ,(char *)lpParam);
   DestIp = inet_addr(look);

   memset(&MacAddr, 0xff, sizeof (MacAddr)); 
   /*Pinging particular ip and retrning mac addrs if response is thr*/
   dwRetVal = SendARP(DestIp, SrcIp, &MacAddr, &PhysAddrLen);
   if (dwRetVal == NO_ERROR) 
   {
       /**/ 
   } 
   return 0;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl PopulateARPTable(char *IpSubNetMask)
{

   char ipn[100];
   char buffer[10];
   unsigned int k;
   DWORD   dwThreadIdArray[260];
   HANDLE  hThreadArray[260]; 

   /*Run 255 threads at once*/
   for (k=1; k<255; k++)
   {
       itoa(k, buffer, 10);
       strcpy(ipn, IpSubNetMask);
       strcat(ipn, "."); 
       strcat(ipn, buffer);

       /*Thread creation */
       hThreadArray[k] = CreateThread( NULL, 0, GetMacAddrOfSubNet, ipn, 0, &dwThreadIdArray[k]);
       if (hThreadArray[k] == NULL) 
       {           
          //ExitProcess(3);
       }
   }
   WaitForMultipleObjects(255, hThreadArray, TRUE, INFINITE);

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: please do not tag spam, this is not C++, I have gone ahead and fixed your tags for you

Answer (score 1):

The `ipn` buffer only exists once. You are using and modifying it as parameter for your (up to) 255 threads. And you expect that the statement `strcpy(look ,(char *)lpParam)` in the thread will be performed **before** the main thread modifies `ipn`again for calling the next thread. But this is not the case, at least it's not guaranteed. So your threads may use wrong parameters.

Either use different buffers for each thread, or implement a synchronization, that ensures that the parameter has been copied by the thread before main thread modifies the buffer again.

Comment: hi thank you for your fast reponse, i used different buffers for each thread but this time only few response came back.(expected result was diff). I did find different way of achieving the same so thank you for your efforts once again

Answer (score 0):

I've done this already for Excel, wrote a multi-threaded DLL that in addition to getting MAC addresses, will do DNS reverse hostname and ICMP ping RT.

Lemme know if you want the VBA code that goes with it.  The source for the C-based DLL (*which you may be happy with as a template*) is:

```
/* 
    ExcelNet library: Provide threaded networking functions 
    NOTE: Serially doing these on the network involves serially waiting for timeouts, much ouchies!
    
    Written by: Danny Holstein
 */
#if 1   //  header stuff
#include <windows.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <icmpapi.h>

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MSEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

#define MIN(a,b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
#define MAX(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))

#define BUFSZ 256
typedef struct {
    char ip[BUFSZ];     //  IP addresses in dotted notation.
    int ipSize;         //  size of IP address buffer
    char data[BUFSZ];   //  general network data (MAC, hostname, etc)
    int dataSize;       //  size of data buffer ^
    int err_no;         //  WinAPI error number
    int (*func)(LPCSTR Addr, char* buf, int BufSz); //  function address, &GetNameInfos, &GetARP or &GetICMP
} NET_DATA;

int GetARP(LPCSTR Addr, char* Buf, int BufSz);
int GetNameInfos(LPCSTR Addr, char* Buf, int BufSz);
int GetICMP(LPCSTR Addr, char* Buf, int BufSz);

char msg_dbg[BUFSZ], dan[BUFSZ];
#define DEBUG_PRT() {snprintf(msg_dbg, BUFSZ, "lineno = %d\tfunc = %s", __LINE__ , __func__); MessageBox(0, msg_dbg, "debug", 0);}
#define DEBUG_MSG(msg) {snprintf(msg_dbg, BUFSZ, "msg=\"%s\"\tlineno = %d\tfunc = %s", msg, __LINE__ , __func__); MessageBox(0, msg_dbg, "debug", 0);}

#if 0   //  documentation indicates malloc/realloc/free shouldn't be used in DLLs
    #define malloc(A) malloc(A)
    #define realloc(A, B) realloc(A, B)
    #define free(A) free(A)
    // #define NOMEMLEAK    //  dudint work
#else   //  kinda works, when NOT allocating all the NET_DATA structure elements
    #define malloc(A) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY | HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS, A)
    #define realloc(A, B) HeapReAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS, A, B)
    #define free(A) (void) HeapFree(A, HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS, NULL)
    #define NOMEMLEAK
#endif
#endif
MSEXPORT  void __stdcall ArrayDGH(SAFEARRAY **IntArr, SAFEARRAY **StrArr)
{
    SAFEARRAY *A = (SAFEARRAY*) (*IntArr);
    SAFEARRAY *S = (SAFEARRAY*) (*StrArr);
    int n = (*A).rgsabound[0].cElements;
    
    snprintf(dan, BUFSZ, "a num elems = %d, str num elems = %d", n, (*S).rgsabound[0].cElements); DEBUG_MSG(dan);
    // for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {snprintf(dan, BUFSZ, "elem[%d] = %d", i, ((int*) (*A).pvData)[i]); DEBUG_MSG(dan);}
    OLECHAR* str[] = {L"Da",L"Fuk",L"Waz",L"Dat?",L"dot",L"dot"};
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {SysReAllocString(&(((BSTR*) (*S).pvData)[i]), str[i]);}
}

DWORD dwMilliseconds = 10000;

MSEXPORT  void __stdcall SetTIMO(DWORD Timo) {dwMilliseconds = Timo;}

MSEXPORT  bool __stdcall ExcelSendARP(LPCSTR Addr, BSTR* MAC)
{
    char buf[BUFSZ];
    int err = GetARP(Addr, buf, BUFSZ);
    *MAC = SysAllocStringByteLen(buf, strlen(buf)); //  avoid WIDE to ANSI stuff
    return !err;
}

MSEXPORT  bool __stdcall ExcelICMPRT(LPCSTR Addr, BSTR* RoundTrip)
{
    char buf[BUFSZ];
    int err = GetICMP(Addr, buf, BUFSZ);
    *RoundTrip = SysAllocStringByteLen(buf, strlen(buf));   //  avoid WIDE to ANSI stuff
    return !err;
}

MSEXPORT  bool __stdcall ExcelGetNameInfo(LPCSTR Addr, BSTR* NameInfo)
{
    char buf[BUFSZ];
#ifdef TEST_FUNC_PTR
    int (*FunAddr[2])(LPCSTR Addr, char** buf, int BufSz);
    FunAddr[0] = &GetARP; FunAddr[1] = &GetNameInfos;  //  DRY code hooks
    int err = (*(FunAddr[1]))(Addr, buf, BUFSZ);
#else
    int err = GetNameInfos(Addr, buf, BUFSZ);
#endif

    *NameInfo = SysAllocStringByteLen(buf, strlen(buf));    //  avoid WIDE to ANSI stuff
    return !err;
}

int GetNameInfos(LPCSTR Addr, char* buf, int BufSz)
{
    ULONG inet; DWORD resp = 0; HOSTENT *tHI;
    struct in_addr addr = { 0 };
    
    if ((inet = inet_addr(Addr)) == INADDR_NONE) {
        if (strcpy_s(buf, BufSz, "inet_addr failed and returned INADDR_NONE")) DEBUG_MSG("strcpy_s error!");
        return inet;
    }
    
    addr.s_addr = inet; tHI = gethostbyaddr((char *) &addr, 4, AF_INET);
    if (tHI == NULL) {  //  no reponse for this IP condition, decode condition and place in PCHAR buf
        resp =  WSAGetLastError();
        FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, 0, resp, 0, buf, BufSz, 0);
        return resp;
    }
    
    _snprintf_s(buf, BufSz-1, _TRUNCATE, "%s", tHI->h_name);    //  place hostname in PCHAR buf
    return resp;    //  <- resp = 0, we have a hostname associated with this IP, SUCCESS!
}

int GetARP(LPCSTR Addr, char* buf, int BufSz)
{
#define BUFLEN 6
    ULONG pMacAddr[BUFLEN], inet, BufLen = BUFLEN; DWORD resp = 0;
    if ((inet = inet_addr(Addr)) == INADDR_NONE) {
        if (strcpy_s(buf, BufSz, "inet_addr failed and returned INADDR_NONE")) DEBUG_MSG("strcpy_s error!");
        return inet;
    }
    resp = SendARP(inet, 0, pMacAddr, &BufLen);
    if (resp) { //  no reponse for this IP condition, decode condition and place in PCHAR buf
        FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, 0, resp, 0, buf, BufSz, 0);
        return resp;
    }
    
    UCHAR *pMacAddrBytes = (UCHAR *) pMacAddr;
    _snprintf_s(buf, BufSz, _TRUNCATE, "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x", pMacAddrBytes[0], pMacAddrBytes[1], pMacAddrBytes[2],
                                                                        pMacAddrBytes[3], pMacAddrBytes[4], pMacAddrBytes[5]);  //  place MAC in PCHAR buf
    return resp;    //  <- resp = 0, we have a MAC associated with this IP, SUCCESS!
}

int GetICMP(LPCSTR Addr, char* buf, int BufSz)
{
    HANDLE hIcmpFile;
    ULONG inet; DWORD resp = 0;
    char SendData[] = "Data Buffer";
    LPVOID ReplyBuffer = NULL;
    DWORD ReplySize = 0;
    
    if ((inet = inet_addr(Addr)) == INADDR_NONE) {
        if (strcpy_s(buf, BufSz, "inet_addr failed and returned INADDR_NONE")) DEBUG_MSG("strcpy_s error!");
        return inet;
    }

    hIcmpFile = IcmpCreateFile();
    if (hIcmpFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        resp =  GetLastError();
        FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, 0, resp, 0, buf, BufSz, 0);
        return resp;
    }
    
    // Allocate space for at a single reply
    ReplySize = sizeof (ICMP_ECHO_REPLY) + sizeof (SendData) + 8;
    ReplyBuffer = (VOID *) malloc(ReplySize);
    
    resp = IcmpSendEcho2(hIcmpFile, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                         inet, SendData, sizeof (SendData), NULL,
                         ReplyBuffer, ReplySize, dwMilliseconds);
    PICMP_ECHO_REPLY pEchoReply = (PICMP_ECHO_REPLY) ReplyBuffer;                    
    if (resp == 0) {    //  no reponse for this IP condition, decode condition and place in PCHAR buf
        resp =  pEchoReply->Status; //  WSAGetLastError();
        FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, 0, resp, 0, buf, BufSz, 0);
        return resp;
    }
    
    _snprintf_s(buf, BufSz-1, _TRUNCATE, "%d", ((PICMP_ECHO_REPLY) ReplyBuffer)->RoundTripTime);    //  place roundtrip time in PCHAR buf (ASCII representation)
    
    IcmpCloseHandle(hIcmpFile);
    return 0;   //  we have a RT time in milliseconds associated with this IP, SUCCESS!
}

NET_DATA *NetData;

DWORD WINAPI tGetDATA(LPVOID NetData)
{
    char buf[BUFSZ];
    NET_DATA *m = NetData;  //  stupid me, I had allocated the space, instead of address of, not thinking it all disappears on exit
    m->err_no = (*(m->func))(m->ip, buf, BUFSZ);    //  GetARP, GetNameInfos or GetICMP
    if (_snprintf_s(m->data, m->dataSize-1, _TRUNCATE, "%s", buf) == -1) DEBUG_MSG("_snprintf_s error!");
    //  A resources error may have hit AFTER the calling function has returned, including having the thread/memory deallocated in the calling function
    return 0;
}

MSEXPORT BSTR __stdcall ExcelRngNetData(UCHAR *list, ULONG *ErrNos, BSTR *DataArry, DWORD dwMilliseconds, char sep, char FunctType)
{   //  take list of IP addresses (newline-separated), create thread for each to get network data.  Return results in (sep-separated) BSTR.
    int i=0, j, NumIPs=0, k = strlen(list), l=0;
    #define NMSZ 100
    char nm[NMSZ];
    void* FuncAddr[3];  //  DRY code hooks
    FuncAddr[0] = &GetARP; FuncAddr[1] = &GetNameInfos; FuncAddr[2] = &GetICMP;
    
    while (i<k && sscanf_s(list+i, "%[^\n]\n", nm, NMSZ)){i += strnlen_s(nm, NMSZ) + 1; NumIPs++;}  //  count newline-separated items before doing malloc(), because realloc() is REALLY resource intensive
    
    NetData = malloc(NumIPs * sizeof(NET_DATA)); i = 0;
    while (i<k && sscanf_s(list+i, "%[^\n]\n", nm, NMSZ)){  //  load calling routines list into structures 
        j = strnlen_s(nm, NMSZ) + 1; i += j;
        NetData[l].err_no = WAIT_TIMEOUT;       //  easy way to preset the error to a TIMEOUT, if the thread successfully completes before the timeout, this will be set to reflect its timeout
        NetData[l].dataSize = BUFSZ;
        NetData[l].func = FuncAddr[FunctType];  //  DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) code hook
        if (strncpy_s(NetData[l].ip, (NetData[l].ipSize = BUFSZ), nm, j)) DEBUG_MSG("strcpy_s error!");
        l++;
    }
    
    HANDLE  *tHandles = malloc(NumIPs * sizeof(HANDLE)); DWORD ThreadId;
    for (i=0; i<NumIPs; i++){
        tHandles[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, tGetDATA, &(NetData[i]), 0, &ThreadId);
        if (tHandles[i] == NULL) {DEBUG_MSG("Could not create threads!\nExiting now"); ExitProcess(3);}
    }
    if(WaitForMultipleObjects(NumIPs, tHandles, TRUE, dwMilliseconds) == WAIT_FAILED) {
        FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, 0, GetLastError(), 0, dan, BUFSZ, 0); DEBUG_MSG(dan);
        //  Prolly means too many threads, kicked in when I exceeded 64; ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER = "The parameter is incorrect"
    }
  
    #define CHUNK 1024
    #define DATASZ 256  //  tested with intentionally small size to check "safe" string functions
    wchar_t wcs[DATASZ]; char MacChunk[DATASZ];
    char *ans = malloc(CHUNK); int anslen = 0, anssz = CHUNK;
    char separator[2]; separator[0] = sep; separator[1] = 0;
    
    for(i=0; i<NumIPs; i++) {   //  build return BSTR and load array with data
        CloseHandle(tHandles[i]); ErrNos[i] = NetData[i].err_no;
        if (strncpy_s(MacChunk, DATASZ-1, NetData[i].err_no == 0 ? NetData[i].data : "", NetData[i].dataSize-1)) DEBUG_MSG("strcpy_s error!");
        if (i<NumIPs-1 && sep != 0) if (strncat_s(MacChunk, DATASZ-1, separator, 1)) DEBUG_MSG("strcpy_s error!");
        while (strnlen_s(MacChunk, DATASZ) > anssz - anslen -1) ans = realloc(ans, (anssz += CHUNK)); // choose CHUNK size to avoid constant realloc(), because realloc() is REALLY resource intensive
        if (strncpy_s(&(ans[anslen]), DATASZ-1, MacChunk, DATASZ-1)) DEBUG_MSG("strcpy_s error!"); anslen += strnlen_s(MacChunk, DATASZ);   //  return data in returned BSTR
        
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0,
                            ErrNos[i] == WAIT_TIMEOUT ? "The wait operation timed out." : NetData[i].data,
                            -1, wcs, DATASZ-1);    // return data in supplied array
        SysReAllocString(&DataArry[i], wcs); 
    }
    BSTR r = SysAllocStringByteLen(ans, strlen(ans));
    
#ifdef NOMEMLEAK
    free(NetData); free(tHandles); free(ans);
#endif

    return r;
}
```